# Does uploading files causes Django server to be unresponsive for other users?

Tags: python, django, file, upload

So as I understood Django framework and python language are synchronous which means things are processed sequentially and only one user can be served at each particular moment.

In that case what happens when a single user tries to upload relatively large file to server. Does the whole web-app become unresponsive for everyone else?

What is the right way to do the file upload in Python anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Django is a Web Framework. Its doesn't get unresponsive when you upload file. Django is run as a WSGI application. Django's request handler is thread-safe.

> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django
>   will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. However, if an
>   uploaded file is too large, Django will write the uploaded file to a
>   temporary file stored in your system’s temporary directory.

To upload file you can use this code

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)

This is old but will give you overview http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/13/how-django-processes-request/

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is it better to use python's tempfile module? What happens with the request.FILES? Is this being automatically deleted?

Comment: yes, request.FILES is a temp file location that is deleted after the request is completed. Where do you want to use tempfile?

Comment: Actually, there is no need for it if the request.FILES is automatically deleted. Thanks a lot for your answers!!!